# Get review status of pull request from Github

Tags: github, github-api

Running on GitHub Enterprise I have a small Jenkins job that looks for pull-request comments and triggers a script depending on the message.

Now I only want to trigger the script if review is already done from GitHub point of view, like all CODE_OWNERS and no additional person requested changes. I don't want to implement that logic myself. GitHub has different section for reviews and status checks. I only want review state, since I am going to set the status myself.

But I was not able to the correct value from the API endpoint. Neither from pull-request itself, nor from pulls/id/reviews.
Closest that i found was "mergeable_state", but this unfortunately takes the status check into consideration.

Is there another place to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we decided to make a Probot app in Github which was able to get all the required information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fetch the global review status. I think that the best you can do is to check that there are no [review requests](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v3/pulls/review_requests/) and fetch all [reviews](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v3/pulls/reviews/) to check if there are no requested changes.

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing before too. But I had a problem with this approach. Just because someone was requested for review does not mean that the PR is blocked because of it. Only if noone else did their review before and if its not under code ownership. Especially when there are several code owners it might get confusing :(